# How to handle security in Quiz applications using angular with webapi or mvc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, angular-directive

i have plan to create a quiz application ,In the quiz application ,where i have keep the data is better which means if i have stored the data in server side in memory or database means,while sending the data to client side,in the http response answer is able to see which lead to json hijacking exploit the app.

if don't want to show the answer in client side how could be handle that?which is better approach in performance side.
eg)
If i have 5 questions ,they have answered 5 questions at the end there have finish button, while clicking the finish button,send to server side and how can  shows the score to the client.

else

2)for every answered request ,have to check it in server side is better?

else isthere any other way to do.

**Method 1:**

```
public JsonResult QuizQuestionAns()  
{  
    List < Questionsoptions > obj = new List < Questionsoptions > ();  
    obj.Add(new Questionsoptions  
    {  
        Question = "What is 12+20?", OpA = "21", OpB = "32", OpC = "41", Ans = "B"  
    });  
    obj.Add(new Questionsoptions  
    {  
        Question = "What is 12+12?", OpA = "10", OpB = "12", OpC = "24", Ans = "C"  
    });  
    obj.Add(new Questionsoptions  
    {  
        Question = "What is 12+24?", OpA = "36", OpB = "24", OpC = "12", Ans = "A"  
    });  
    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

angular:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
```

**/// response get the answer**  // attacks

```
  }, function errorCallback(response) {

  });
```

External Json:

**If I store the Questions in Json,How much secure it is?
**

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
// In the response we will get the object and attack
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });**
```

**

**Method 3:**

If  store it in Object inside the app,also able to see in client side.

How to make more secure quiz app without seeing the answer in clientside.

In the below example have stored the question and answer in array:anybody can see it .

```
angular.module('quiz.service', []);
angular.module('quiz.directive', []);
angular.module('quiz.filter', []);

angular.module('quiz', ['quiz.service','quiz.directive','quiz.filter']);

var QuizController = function($scope){

  "use strict";
  $scope.questions = [
    {"questionText": "Why is the sky blue?", "answers": [
      {"answerText":"blah blah 1", "correct": true},
      {"answerText":"blah blah 2", "correct": false},
      {"answerText":"blah blah 3", "correct": false}
      ]},
    {"questionText": "Why is the meaning of life?", "answers": [
      {"answerText":"blah blah 1", "correct": true},
      {"answerText":"blah blah 2", "correct": false},
      {"answerText":"blah blah 3", "correct": false}
      ]},
    {"questionText": "How many pennies are in $10.00?", "answers": [
      {"answerText":"1,000.", "correct": true},
      {"answerText":"10,000.", "correct": false},
      {"answerText":"A lot", "correct": false}
      ]},
    {"questionText": "What is the default program?", "answers": [
      {"answerText":"Hello World.", "correct": true},
      {"answerText":"Hello Sunshine.", "correct": false},
      {"answerText":"Hello my ragtime gal.", "correct": false}
      ]}
  ];
  $scope.answers ={};
  $scope.correctCount = 0;
  $scope.showResult = function(){
    $scope.correctCount = 0;
    var qLength = $scope.questions.length;
    for(var i=0;i<qLength;i++){
      var answers = $scope.questions[i].answers;
      $scope.questions[i].userAnswerCorrect = false;
      $scope.questions[i].userAnswer = $scope.answers[i];
      for(var j=0;j<answers.length;j++){
        answers[j].selected = "donno";
        if ($scope.questions[i].userAnswer === answers[j].answerText && answers[j].correct===true){
          $scope.questions[i].userAnswerCorrect = true;
          answers[j].selected = "true";
          $scope.correctCount++;
        }else if($scope.questions[i].userAnswer === answers[j].answerText && answers[j].correct===false){
          answers[j].selected = "false";
        }
      }
    }

    //console.log($scope.answers);

  };
};
```

[image]

can i use Json padding to avoid this ? is there any other way to prevent?

Comment: If you don't want users to see answers, you must never send them to the client.

Comment: I've implemented a quiz app similar to this as a side project. There are many ways to do this, but one way is that your server returns which one was the correct answer *after* the user submits their answer. You can't send the answer to the client in any shape or form before they have answered. Even then in some apps you would never send it, just showing a score at the end instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show a user if answer is correct or not, send an answer to the current question to the server and send both next question and result in response. This way they are also unlikely to cheat by downloading a full list of questions and taking quiz after finding answers in case quiz is time limited.

If you don't need to show user if answer is correct, just show next question instantly and send an answer to the server in background.